# Rails: AWS S3 Access denied error with Paperclip upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, paperclip

I am getting `Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied` whenever I tries to upload an image using paperclip and aws-sdk-s3.

I have almost tried all the solution available on Internet.

I have tried configuring paperclip default option from [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3)

Gems used
`gem "paperclip", git: "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git" and gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1'`

My **development.rb** file configuration looks like

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :s3,
    path: '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename',
    s3_credentials: {
      access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
      s3_region: ENV['AWS_REGION'],
    },
    bucket: ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
  }
```

My **model.rb** file looks like

```
has_attached_file :photo
has_attached_file :image
has_attached_file :signature
```

My **paperclip.rb** file looks like

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_protocol] = 'http'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
```

My **aws.yml** file looks like

```
development:
    access_key_id: MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    secret_access_key: MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

I am using `gem 'figaro'` to save my environment variable for development environment.

May if someone can assists me would be appreciated.

Comment: Here you seem adding bucket under s3_credentials not outside, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#configuration

Comment: @MuhammedKılıç thanks for your reply, but I also tried configuring using you suggested documentation. But, unfortunately it doesn't worked.

Comment: Can you try by adding raw data instead of environment variables?

Comment: @MuhammedKılıç, I tried using raw data, but again it didn't worked.

Comment: Error says "access denied", so in my opinion problem is probably with config keys etc.

Comment: @MuhammedKılıç, I am able to use the same credentials from aws cli to add or remove files.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me getting Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied was my canned ACL properties were not configured properly.

Thanks, It might help someone.